# How do I make Clonezilla Server (DRBL) restore to only one machine in a network?

Tags: clonezilla, drbl

If I have 100 machines, but I only want to restore/push and image to five of them, how can I set DRBL to do that?  I am afraid that if something other than one of those five reboots, it will get pushed an image.  That would be [bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyaLZHiJJnE).

Do I need to put them all (the five) on a private network first?

Answer (score 1):

Collect clients' MAC addresses and use those to divide clients into different groups and then perform the installation. https://wiki.epfl.ch/icit/internal/clonezilla/installconfig